# Remove LabelFrame border - tkinter Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to remove the upper border of a LabelFrame tkinter widget, but I cannot find a way.

I tried to suppress the border by stating `highlightthickness=0` and `borderwidth=0`. The border disappears but my intent is to remove only its upper part, if this is possible.

See the attached [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veJzW.png).

Many thanks in advance for your help.